# Embedding virtualsky library into react component

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I want to create react component library that will embed [Virtualsky](https://virtualsky.lco.global)

I have already walk over [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html), much of stackoverflow topics, have try use react-helmet library and I cant wrote anything that can looks like it can work.

Can anyone give me some good examplle or advice that will lead me. Thx.

Edit:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'https://slowe.github.io/VirtualSky/stuquery.min.js'
import 'https://slowe.github.io/VirtualSky/virtualsky.min.js'
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const VirtualSky = props => {
  const id = "test";
  const width = "500px";
  const height = "500px";

  useEffect(() => {
    const planetarium = $.virtualsky({ id });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id={id} style={{ width, height }} />
  );
};

export default VirtualSky;
```

Whatever I do, always get "virtualsky" is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the jQuery plugin inside the `useEffect` hook.

Something like this:

```
const VisualSky = ({  id, width, height }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const planetarium = $.virtualsky({ id });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id={id} style={{ width, height }} />
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <VisualSky id="startmap" width={500} heigh={500} />
);
```

Comment: Thx Carlos for your example.I have try to use it but whatever I do, always get "virtualsky" is not a function. Can you help. I pass my code to yesterdays question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few years old but I ran a very similar issue this week (Sept 2023) which I believe is caused by the same problem.

**The Cause:**

The current repo code was refactored to use the stuQuery library which you correctly included.
Unfortunately it seems as if the Virtualsky examples haven't been updated to reflect this and are still using jQuery.

**The Solution:**

Replace '$' with 'S' which is what stuQuery uses to avoid conflicts with jQuery.

```
    const planetarium = S.virtualsky({ id });
```